# adding the result of count in Oracle Sql

Tags: sql

I'm trying to the number of the elements of two tables here is what I've tried  :

```
 select 
((select count(*) from Person,Professor where ID_Person = ID_Professor)  + 
(select count(*) from Person, Student where ID_Person = ID_Student ))
```

well this doesn't work any Idea how can I do this? 
thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're just missing a `from dual` on the end, to make the outer select a complete statement.

Exactly as you had it plus `from dual`:

```
select 
((select count(*) from Person,Professor where ID_Person = ID_Professor)  + 
(select count(*) from Person, Student where ID_Person = ID_Student ))
from dual
```

Comment: thanks for your answer, but honestly I don't get what do you mean ?

Answer (score 1):

Wumpus Q. Wumbley has given correct suggestion for Oracle database.

For your question you can try following query as well -

```
   select sum(c_total) 
    from (
      select (select count(*) from professor 
               where professor.id_professor=person.id_person)
           + (select count(*) from student 
               where student.id_student=person.id_person) c_total
      from person
     group by person.id_person)
```